# Set label over node in tikzcd without change of spacing

Tags: labels, tikz-cd

I would like to label a node using tikz-cd without change of vertical spacing between rows.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}


\begin{document}

$$
\begin{tikzcd}
    A \ar{r} & B \ar{d} \\
    C \ar{r} & D
\end{tikzcd}
\quad
\begin{tikzcd}
    A \ar{r} & B \ar{d} \\
    \overset{*}{C} \ar{r} & D
\end{tikzcd}
\quad
\begin{tikzcd}
    A \ar{r} & B \ar{d} \\
    |[label=*]|{C} \ar{r} & D
\end{tikzcd}
$$
\end{document}
```

[image: three diagrams]

On the left you see the diagram without any label. I would like to have the same distance between the two rows when I add a label * over C. The two diagrams on the right show futile attempts to do so.

Comment: Welcome! My suggestion would be to just draw it in one single `tikzcd` diagram. If you have linebreaks between them I wouldn't worry about the distance between rows. That said, we can use [`between origins`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-matrices#sec-20.3.2) (which might lead to overlap if not tended to) or `overlay` with the label (i.e. `|[label={[overlay]*}]|`) or something similar to the overset. You will aready have different vertical alignment, if one cell contains a fraction and another one doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will depend on the content of your labels/overset and if you want arrows to consider the labels/oversets in any form.

Here are a few approaches:

- For `\overset`, you can use `\ooverset` which will ignore the vertical dimension of the overset.
- For the label:

  - You can `overlay` it which will make TikZ not consider it for the bounding box of the cell or the whole diagram. → Add `overlay` to `/tikz/every label`.
  - You can add it later when the matrix is built. → Use `cd label`.

Finally, you can just set the `row sep`aration to use `between origins`. This places the center of all nodes on a grid with a fixed distance, ignoring the content of the cells. You can now use `\overset` and the normal `label` without it affecting the vertical spacing.

---

All these solutions have the disadvantages that things may overlap when not taken care of.

Except for the `\overset`-`between origins` combo, neither `*` will be
considered when placing an arrow that meets `C` from somewhere above.

### Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth, class=amsart]{standalone}
%\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand*\ooverset[2]{\vphantom{#2}\smash{\overset{#1}{#2}}}
\tikzset{
  cd label/.code={%
    \arrow[to path={% math-mode because everything else is also math mode
      [every label/.append style={execute at begin node=$,execute at end node=$}]
      node also[label={#1}](\tikztostart)}]%
  }
}
\begin{document}

Setting the row separation to \texttt{between origins}:
\[
\tikzcdset{diagrams={row sep={3.75em,between origins}}}
\begin{tikzcd}
    A \ar{r} & B \ar{d} \\
    C \ar{r} & D
\end{tikzcd}
\quad
\begin{tikzcd}
    A \ar{r} & B \ar{d} \\
    \overset{*}{C} \ar{r} & D
\end{tikzcd}
\quad
\begin{tikzcd}
    A \ar{r} & B \ar{d} \\
    |[label=*]|{C} \ar{r} & D
\end{tikzcd}
\]\medskip

Using \texttt{\string\ooverset} instead of \texttt{\string\overset}
and \texttt{overlay}ing the label(s):
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
    A \ar{r} & B \ar{d} \\
    C \ar{r} & D
\end{tikzcd}
\quad
\begin{tikzcd}
    A \ar{r} & B \ar{d} \\
    \ooverset{*}{C} \ar{r} & D
\end{tikzcd}
\quad
\begin{tikzcd}[/tikz/every label/.append style={overlay}]
    A \ar{r} & B \ar{d} \\
    |[label=*]|{C} \ar{r} & D
\end{tikzcd}
\]\medskip

Using \texttt{\string\ooverset} (again)
and a \texttt{cd label}, a label that isn't overlayed
but gets added after the matrix has been built.
This is almost like \texttt{overlay}.
The label still contributes to the bounding box of the TikZ picture
but not that of the cells.
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
    A \ar{r} & B \ar{d} \\
    C \ar{r} & D
\end{tikzcd}
\quad
\begin{tikzcd}
    A \ar{r} & B \ar{d} \\
    \ooverset{*}{C} \ar{r} & D
\end{tikzcd}
\quad
\begin{tikzcd}
    A \ar{r} & B \ar{d} \\
    |[cd label=*]|{C} \ar{r} & D
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the extensive solutions. From my perspective, the last overlay version is the best, as it is functional and minimal. I could not locate this solution in the pgfmanual.

Answer (score 2):

Since arrows don't change the spacing between cells, you can place your label above a phantom arrow (that doesn't point anywhere):

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
    A \ar{r} & B \ar{d} \\
    C \ar{r} & D
\end{tikzcd}
\quad
\begin{tikzcd}
    A \ar{r} & B \ar{d} \\
    {C} \ar{r}\ar[phantom, "*"above=4pt] & D
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. However, I think using the phantom arrow is a bit brutal. Nevertheless, this seems to be the most elementary solution.